# Unable to navigate to app or app events while clicking on notification badges on plasma workspace for Flatpak apps

Tags: fedora, kde, plasma, notifications, flatpak

Normally, when I click on the notification badges, I am taken to the application window for any application in KDE plasma. However, this is not the case with Flatpak apps. Clicking on the notification badges for flatpak apps do nothing.

My question is why this is happening? And is there any solution to this kind of behavior of Flatpak apps on plasma workspace?

My OS is Nobara Linux 38 and DE is KDE plasma.